# How do I set up visual studio Remote Debugger to go over Ethernet?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8, remote-debugging, windows-rt

I want to debug an app remotely on Windows RT (though this applies to any remote debugging, I guess), I don't want to open up my WiFi connection wide or handle complex software configuration every time I connect (firewall etc.).

I thought that maybe by using an Ethernet connection between my Surface and my dev machine, I could make the remote debugging work on top of that. Installing an Ethernet USB dongle on top of Surface seems to be easy, but I can't figure out how to make my dev machine actually find the Surface computer on it.

My set up is simple, dev machine connected to ethernet cable, connected to USB dongle, connected to Surface (Windows RT). Even when disabling WiFi, the remote debugger cannot find the debugee.

Do I need to manually set up the IP address or something?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to manually set up the IP address or something?

That's what I was thinking. What happens when you try to ping one machine from the the other? Does either machine run a DHCP server? If not you could run a DHCP server (probably on your dev machine) or setup a static IP address. Setting up DHCP may be harder at first but more convenient if you need to connect your tablet to other networks.

For testing it might be helpful to wire both devices to a router so you can configure and test Remote Debugging separately.